# Multiple methods named 'tag' found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

why do I get this warning in my code below:

```
- (IBAction)shareThisActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    int row = [sender tag]; //warning is here! Multiple methods named 'tag' found
    ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Description**

The problem is that the compiler sees more than one method named `tag` in the current translation unit, and these declarations have different return types. One is likely to be `-[UIView tag]`, which returns an `NSInteger`. But it's also seen another declaration of `tag`, perhaps:

```
@interface MONDate
- (NSString *)tag;
@end
```

then the compiler sees an ambiguity - is `sender` a `UIView`? or is it a `MONDate`?

The compiler's warning you that it has to *guess* what `sender`'s type is. That's really asking for undefined behavior.

**Resolution**

If you know the parameter's type, then specify it:

```
- (IBAction)shareThisActionSheet:(id)sender
{
 UIView * senderView = sender;
 int row = [senderView tag];
 ...
```

else, use something such as an `isKindOfClass:` condition to determine the type to declare the variable as before messaging it. as other answers show, you could also typecast.

Comment: +1 very well explained. But it should work in any case (using id), despite the warning.. right?

Comment: @Ankit It *won't* work (ref: it's asking for undefined behavior). If all visible `tag` methods return an objc object, that's predictable. If one returns a `CGRect` and the other an objc object, the compiler may end up calling the wrong `objc_msgSend` variant you may smash part of your stack. If the compiler guesses the other way and is wrong, the `CGRect` may be messaged as an objc object. You could also slice memory, and if C++ is in there, it's even more complex. (cont)

Comment: (cont) The alternative would be to look at the assembly generated, for each warning generated. What's worse? You may not get the warning if you have not #included the type of the object that is passed as `sender` in the TU.

Comment: this one works. thanks for the explanation. I just casted it to UIButton instead of UIView.

Comment: Shouldn't the runtime know the actual class of the id, so to use the right `tag` method? I mean when ClassB derives from ClassA and both have a method named `tag`, when such calls to instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB`, shouldn't invoke the corresponding methods? OR the problem appears in return types?

Comment: @VassilisGr absolutely - the objc runtime does execute the correct method/implementation. the problem is that without the static type information, the parameters and return type are not known to the compiler because it sees multiple choices. the compiler does not know how to set up the function call without the disambiguation. if the function call is set up wrong, it is undefined behavior. (cont)

Comment: @VassilisGr (cont) examples: the method may return a different sized type or parameter and overwrite arbitrary memory or read from the wrong memory regions. with ARC, the implementation performs reference counting on your behalf and could perform reference count operations on the `NSInteger` (an integral e.g. `long`, not objc object) value returned by the actual implementation in the example above -- if the compiler were allowed to guess (and guessed wrong) or if the author specified the incorrect type.

Comment: Use  `long row = [senderView tag];`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `sender` is defined as a `(id)` object. At compile time xcode does not know what kind of objects will get passed to your function.

If you write this function for a specific object type, you could you could write for example

```
- (IBAction)shareThisActionSheet:(UIButton*)sender
```

or you could hint the compiler the type of object with the call

```
int row = [(UIButton*)sender tag];
```

Comment: Use  `long row = [senderView tag];`

Answer (score 2):

Bastian is right you should convert your sender to button like this:

```
UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
int row = button.tag;
```

Comment: if you think that I'm right, why do you post the same answer instead of upvoting mine ?

Comment: Because i posted a bit different casting of sender(I think it is more correct because it is more visual)

Comment: Use  `long row = [senderView tag];`